# How to check columns and subgrids (Sudoku Checker in Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file, sudoku

I'm doing the traditional "Sudoku Puzzle Checker" activity, and I've only been able to figure out how to check the rows so far. As per instruction, I'm suppose to check (in 3 separate functions), the rows, columns, and subgrids (the 3x3 squares) of a solved sudoku puzzle (given in a .csv file). I understand *how* to do the columns (add 9 each time, 9 times starting numbers ranging from 0-8) and the subgrids (range of 3 numbers, add 6 to get to the next range of 3 numbers e.t.c) but I'm confused as how to implement these concepts into my code. Here's what I have right now:

```
def load_puzzle(filename):

    file = open(filename, 'r')

    puzzle = list(file)

    #the puzzle currently looks like this:
    ['5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2\n', '6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8\n', '1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7\n', '8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3\n', '4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1\n', '7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6\n', '9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4\n', '2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5\n', '3,4,5,2,8,6,1,7,9\n']

    print_puzzle(puzzle)



def print_puzzle(puzzle):

    print(" ")

    count = 0

    while count <= 8:
        line = list(puzzle[count])
        line = [x for x in line if x != ',']
        line.remove('\n')
        line.insert(3, '|')
        line.insert(7, '|')
        if count == 3 or count == 6:
            print("---------------------")
        fresh = ' '.join(line)
        count += 1

    print('''
Checking puzzle...
    ''')

    delimiter = ','
    together = delimiter.join(puzzle)
    new = list(together)
    new[:] = [x for x in new if x != ',']
    new[:] = [x for x in new if x != '\n']

    check_rows(new)

    #the puzzle now looks like this:
    ['5', '3', '4', '6', '7', '8', '9', '1', '2', '6', '7', '2', '1', '9', '5', '3', '4', '8', '1', '9', '8', '3', '4', '2', '5', '6', '7', '8', '5', '9', '7', '6', '1', '4', '2', '3', '4', '2', '6', '8', '5', '3', '7', '9', '1', '7', '1', '3', '9', '2', '4', '8', '5', '6', '9', '6', '1', '5', '3', '7', '2', '8', '4', '2', '8', '7', '4', '1', '9', '6', '3', '5', '3', '4', '5', '2', '8', '6', '1', '7', '9']

def check_numbers(numbers):

    my_list = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']

    numbers.sort()

    if numbers == my_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False



def check_rows(n):

    count = 0
    start = 0

    while count <= 8:
        row = n[start:(start + 9)]

        if check_numbers(row) is True:
            count += 1
            start += 9
        elif check_numbers(row) is False:
            break

    if count == 9:
        print("Rows okay...")
    else:
        print("Error in row", count)


    check_columns(n)


def check_columns(n):

    count = 0
    start = 0

    while count <= 8:
        col = n[start::9]

        if check_numbers(col) is True:
            count += 1
            start += 1
        elif check_numbers(col) is False:
            break

    if count == 9:
        print("Columns okay...")
    else:
        print("Error in row", count)  

def check_subgrids(n):


filename = input("Enter file name of solved sudoku puzzle: ")

load_puzzle(filename)
```

I'm looking for a way to find the columns and subgrids similar to how I found the rows (i.e. `row = n[start:(start + 9)]`) if that's possible. I'm a beginner, so I'm also happy to learn about different tools/ways I could improve my code!

Edit: I've solved my problem with the check_columns function (code updated) but still would appreciate some guidance for the check_subgrid function!

Comment: Slicing has an optional third argument, called the "stride", which grabs every Nth value: `column = n[start::9]`

Comment: @JohnGordon this exactly what I was looking for for the check_columns function, thank you!